# generic linkedlist c++ implementation in c

Tags: c++, generics, linked-list

I was trying to implement generic linked list of objects in C++. But when I fetch the same object twice it gives me different results. I feel it is due to misuse of pointers. Please help me debug.

Here is the Node implementation. I have used pointers for templates since linked list shall contain user defined objects.

```
 template <class T> class Node{
 private:
 T* value;
 Node<T>* next;        
 public:
 Node(T* v){value = v; next = NULL;}
 Node(T* v, Node<T>* n){value = v; next = n;}
 T* getElement(){return value;}
 Node<T>* getNext(){return next;}
 };
```

Here is the implementation for generic linked list.

```
 template <class T> class LinkedList{
 public:
 Node<T>* head = NULL;
 LinkedList(){}    
 LinkedList(T* value){
    Node<T> node(value);
    head = &node;
}
Node<T>* getHead(){
    return head;
}
void add(T* value){
    Node<T> node(value,head);
    head = &node;
}  
};
```

Main function:
When I call head of linked list, it gives me 2 different answers. In this code, Complex is a simple class to hold complex objects.

```
  int main(){
  Complex c1(1,2); Complex c2(3,4); Complex c3(5,6);
  LinkedList<Complex> list(&c1);
  list.add(&c2);
  cout<<list.head->getElement()->i<<" "<<list.getHead()->getElement()->j<<endl;
  cout<<list.head->getElement()->i<<" "<<list.getHead()->getElement()->j<<endl;
  return 0;
  }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `C` does not have classes, so you can't implement a class in `C` using `classes`. Try using a struct.

Comment: Use your debugger. SO is not a debugging service. After you trace the issue you can ask a question if you don't understand why the code is executing the way it is but at that point you'll have all the details of what is happening to put in your question.

Comment: Why not just use `std::list` and be done with it?

Comment: "I have used pointers for templates since linked list shall contain user defined objects." There is no need for pointers. Templating allows `Node` to hold a copy of the source data just as easily as a pointer to it and eliminates the mess you're about to walk into regarding who owns and is responsible for freeing the storage.

Comment: @user4581301 I wanted to add a method to compare objects for any user defined class. If I copy, "==" operator shall always return NO. So, I must pass pointers so that they share same memory space.

Answer (score 2):

In `LinkedList(T* value)` and `void add(T* value)`, you are taking the address of a temporary with `head = &node;`.  As soon as you are out of the scope of that function, `head` becomes a dangling pointer.

You need to create a new node on the heap so that its lifetime will extend beyond the scope of that function.

```
Node<T> node = new Node<T>(value);
```

Don't forget to `delete` all the nodes you have created in the destructor to avoid memory leaks, or even better, switch to smart pointers instead of raw pointers so the cleanup is done for you.

Comment: Upvoted, but recommend swapping "on the heap" for "in dynamic memory". That way you have the rare cases where dynamic memory is not implemented with a heap covered.